# IOS 10 Music App and Music Videos

Tags: itunes, music, ios

Where are the music videos in ios 10? they are not in the built-in video app.

Answer (score 1):

Music videos are located in the Music app.  See [this article](https://9to5mac.com/2016/06/13/new-ios-10-music-app-design/) describing the new Music app.

> The “Browse” tab is also entirely new, replacing the “New” tab. Along the top are side-scrolling headers much like we’ve seen in the past, but otherwise the interface is very simplistic. There are quick links to “New Music,” “Curated Playlists,” “Top Charts,” and “Genres.” The “New Music” interface shows “Hot Tracks,” new albums, new music playlist, new artists, music videos, and “Featured Curators.”